# Is 'potential' countable noun?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I've konwn that 'potential' is uncountable noun so far. But i saw one vedio named Vox channel which said

> "In any human endeavor, There is a potential for error"

In that sentence, potential is used as countable noun, right?

I don't know which is correct. I want you, experts to help me know it correctly. Thanks.!

[image]

Plus, i don't think they had a mistake. Because they said "a potential" in the vedio and they made a subtitle on screen at the same time....

Comment: It isn't clear whether the phrasing "*the* potential for error" is countable.  The uncountable sense might be better represented here as "*some* potential for error".

Comment: A lot of subtitles on Youtube are automatic. Might they have said "there is, uh, potential for error"?

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster allows 'potential' to be a countable noun:

> potential noun
>
> 1a : something that can develop or become actual
>
> **a potential** for violence

[Potential](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/potential)

We can talk about the embodiment of an ordinarily non-count attribute in a person or thing - she had a singular grace and a wonderful lightness when playing the piano; he had a weight and a stature as a politician that were useful to his party.

Answer (score -1):

***Potential*** can be a countable noun - in physics (and electrical work, for the same reason). In the sense of "potential for error", it is generally uncountable, you are correct. It would be most standard to say "**the** potential for error" or just "potential for error".

However, you will get indefinite articles before *potential* when it is an adjective - one might talk about something as "**a** potential error".

It is possible that the speaker slipped. This sort of slip is common enough that it might even be considered a variant in itself.

Answer (score -1):

"*A* potential for error" is an odd expression, as it suggests there is more than one kind of potential for error.  This makes little sense in this context, which is making a general philosophical statement.  Perhaps the video goes into more detail about the various kinds of potential for error, but why?  I would instead have said:

> In any human endeavor there is the potential for **various kinds of error**

retaining "potential" as an uncountable noun.

Again, it's strange.  I'm not going to say that the speaker in the video made a mistake, or is not a native English speaker, but it's possible they are unfamiliar with the typical way this idea is expressed.

In any case, to answer your question:  Yes, in this particular use "potential" (meaning "capacity") is a countable noun, but in the same way you can turn any uncountable noun into a countable noun, if you want.

> "I like to enjoy **a music** in the evenings," he said.  "Sometimes **more than one music**, if I'm feeling indulgent."

With creative writing, anything is possible.  You just have to be aware the reader might misunderstand what you write, or dismiss it as nonsense.

Comment: There's a potential for error when x do y. I see  nothing odd about it.